# Form not submitting contents in Laravel

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel-5.4

I am working on a form in **Laravel framework** whereby I want when the user clicks on the submit button , the content from the form fields is submitted to the controller which later saves it in the database. I am using **jquery to pull data from the form**. But the problem is the data is not being submitted into the database, I have tried to **debug by first logging the data in console tab but nothing is submitted**... Please assist?

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('createClass') }}" class="form-horizontal" id="frm-create-class" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="active" id="active" value="1">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            {{-----------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="academic-year"> Academic Year</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="acdemic_id" id="academic_id">
                                        @foreach($academics as $key => $y)
                                            <option value="{{ $y->academic_id}}"> {{ $y->academic }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-academic"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{-----------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="academic-year"> Course</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">
                                        <option value="">---------------</option>
                                        @foreach($programs as $key => $p)
                                            <option value="{{ $p->program_id }}"> {{ $p->program }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-program"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <label for="academic-year"> Level</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="level_id" id="level_id">

                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-level"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="academic-year"> Shift</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="shift_id" id="shift_id">
                                        @foreach($shift as $shf)
                                            <option value="{{ $shf->shift_id }}"> {{ $shf->shift }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-shift"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="time"> Time</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="time_id" id="time_id">
                                        @foreach($time as $t)
                                            <option value="{{ $t->time_id }}"> {{ $t->time }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-time"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="batch"> Batch</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="batch_id" id="batch_id">
                                        @foreach($batch as $b)
                                            <option value="{{ $b->batch_id }}"> {{ $b->batch }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-Batch"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <label for="group"> Group</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="group_id" id="group_id">
                                        @foreach($group as $g)
                                            <option value="{{ $g->group_id }}"> {{ $g->groups }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-Group"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="startDate"> Start Date</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start_date">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {{---------------------------------------}}
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="endDate"> End Date</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end_date" id="end_date">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  <!-- END FORM GROUP-->
                    </div>   <!-- END PANEL BODY-->

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" > Create Course </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Jquery code tht submits the data to the controller and logs it in console tab

```
$('#frm-create-class').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');

            $.post(url, data, function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
            $(this).trigger('reset');
        });
```

**CourseController**
The controller file

```
 public function createClass(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            return (MyClass::create($request->all()));
        }
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/manage/course/class' , 'CourseController@createClass')->name('createClass');
```

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('class_id');
            $table->integer('academic_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('level_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('shift_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('time_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('batch_id')->unsigned();
            $table->date('start_date');
            $table->date('end_date');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps(); 
            $table->foreign('academic_id')->references('academic_id')->on('academics');
            $table->foreign('level_id')->references('level_id')->on('levels');
            $table->foreign('shift_id')->references('shift_id')->on('shifts');
            $table->foreign('time_id')->references('time_id')->on('times');
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('group_id')->on('groups');
            $table->foreign('batch_id')->references('batch_id')->on('batches');
        });
```

Comment: We must see your `createClass` page. If `console.log(data);` prints right, then the problem is in `createClass`.

Comment: @YusufKandemir console.log(data)  does not print  in console tab.

Comment: @YusufKandemir      seems the bug is in the view which am unable to locate

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `data` variable conflicts for a chance?

Comment: And implement a fail function to see if there is something weird or just post is not executing correct.
 `.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })`
Also semicolon is missing after post.

Comment: What do you mean by  "conflict" ? Ok let me try

Comment: @YusufKandemir   Have tried your advice but the fail function does not execute...$('#frm-create-class').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   var url = $(this).attr('action');

   
   $.post(url, data, function(data){
    $.fail(function(){
     alert('error');
    })
   });
   $(this).trigger('reset');
  });

Comment: @YusufKandemir   Kindly would you show me an alternative method when using $.post in jquery

Comment: You must apply it to post function not inside it.
`$.post(url, data, function(data){console.log(data);}).fail(function(){ alert('error'); }); `

Comment: @YusufKandemir  It has shown an alert message of error,, seems post method is not executing correctly... I have also tried to log data in console without using post and it logs fine..:    `$('#frm-create-class').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   console.log(data);
  });`  How can I resolve the post method problem..

Comment: I don't know why you don't write error but you can use [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @YusufKandemir What I meant is that I implemented your code of: `$.post(url, data, function(data){
     console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(){ 
     alert('error'); 
   });` and it displayed an alert message of error in browser window, I also tried to add this code: `$('#frm-create-class').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); var data = $(this).serialize(); console.log(data); });` and it logged all the data well,  seems the **$.post()** method is the problem ..?

Comment: @YusufKandemir Would you mind checking the question, I have added the code of the controller, route and migration respectively,,, Thanks for your time?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstanded 'alert message of error'. Can you change `$.post(url, data, function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })`
to
`$.post(url, data, function(test){
    console.log(test);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        //add console.logs or alerts to learn what is actually going on
    };`

Comment: @YusufKandemir  I have added the code as you advised me: `$.post(url, data, function(test){ 
    console.log(test); }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
     console.log(error);
   };` It displays this error message in console **Empty string passed to getElementById()**  on line.                                                                      
**jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:10450**

Comment: Why you are using 2012 version of jQuery? And did you also get status?

Comment: @YusufKandemir  Glad you are back, when I log **xhr**  I get the following in console `Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), then: then(), … }`   when I use **status**  I get the following in console  `error         
course:847:13`

Comment: When I try using **error** I get the following in console  `Internal Server Error course:847:13
`   Sorry about the **Empty string passed to getElementById()** message above, I had omitted  a closing parenthesis in my code

Comment: Try to log `xhr.statusCode`

Comment: I get this code `statusCode()
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: "statusCode"
__proto__: ()
apply: function apply()
arguments: null
bind: function bind()
call: function call()
caller: null
constructor: function Function()
isGenerator: function isGenerator()
length: 0
name: ""
toSource: function toSource()
toString: function toString()
Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): undefined
__proto__: Object { … }`

Comment: Try `xhr.statusCode()` and `xhr.status`.

Comment: When using `xhr.status`   I get **500**  in console

Comment: I don't know laravel actually but after looking at docs I think if you change `Route::post('/manage/course/class' ...` to `Route::post('manage/course/class' ...` it might be fixed. Try that and check if status is 500 still or changed.

Comment: Try following after trying previous comment. Another possibility is controller issue. You can try commenting out if statement in controller page for debugging. If the problem is fixed then the problem is in that code.

Comment: @YusufKandemir Thank you very much for your time,, Although the bug still persists, the status does not change from 500 after trying your recommendation

Comment: What about second one?

Comment: Also the 2nd one...

Comment: I hope this will fix your problem finally : [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)